# FastHub for GitHub

Tags: applications, google-play-store, developer-options, open-source, development

I've used the FastHub for GitHub Android app in the past, but can no longer find it on the Google Play store. Has it been replaced by the GitHub app for Android?

What are the differences, or any changes, between the two apps (if any)?

Why has the old app been delisted?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

FastHub Android app was an OpenSource app [hostet on Github](https://github.com/k0shk0sh/FastHub). The whole repository had been archived (thus discontinued in Spetember 2021). The project does not contain any description why it was discontinued. So we can only assume that the author lost interest on it or something else happened.

But as FastHub is open source it was not lost. Looking at the "Network Graph" (see "Insights" -> "Network graph") of the project you can see that multiple forks exist, e.g. [FastHub-REFastHub-RE(vival) by LightDestory](https://github.com/LightDestory/FastHub-RE), [OctoHub by HardcodedCat](https://github.com/HardcodedCat/OctoHub) and [OctoHub by vaginessa](https://github.com/vaginessa/OctoHub).

It seem like [OctoHub by HardcodedCat](https://github.com/HardcodedCat/OctoHub) is the main project, unfortunately it has no binary releases, thus the only way to get the app seems to check-up the source code and compile it your self (requires Android SDK).